# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, python-kivy

Olá, estou fazendo alguns testes com o framework **Kivy** e me está sendo apresentado este erro:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Pois bem, segue o código **Python**:

```
class Window(BoxLayout):

    text = StringProperty('Nome')
    screen_manager = ScreenManager()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(Window, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Main(App):

    def build(self):

        return Window()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Main().run()
```

E o código em **KV language**:

```
<Window>:
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: app.root.text
```

Comment: O objeto `app.root` aparentemente não está definido.

Comment: Também percebi isso, e achei até estranho o obeto ser `None`, mas de acordo com a documentação (https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html?highlight=app%20root#kivy.app.App.root),  o objeto **root** é setado automaticamente pelo método **build** (neste caso).